# It's paying Russian bills in Europe becoming less economic?

Tags: eur-euro, rub-ruble

I pay some bills in rubles. My currency is euros.

Over the past year I have noticed that I pay more euros for the same bill. Do rubles have a tendency to increase in value regarding Euros? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on the timescale. As you can see [here](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/policy_and_exchange_rates/euro_reference_exchange_rates/html/eurofxref-graph-rub.en.html), the ruble has lost against the Euro on a ten-year scale, but it went up during the last three months.

I would characterize this as a recovery from a short drop three months ago.

Comment: Regarding the timescale I would say that my question refereed to the future, something that I see that its risky to ask here - Your reference was really good for me, since, I think its the only answer - looking for the past and drawing my own conclusions.